# Can a power cut damage a laptop?

Tags: laptop, battery, power-management

Okay, I was a rendering a video and suddenly the power cut and the laptop started to run on battery. My question is if it will damage something?

Comment: While a power outage will not damage a computer, it can lead in some cases to data loss if you don't have a battery installed.

Answer (score 2):

Short: No not really.

Laptops are made with the fact in mind, that the power cable can be plugged out anytime while your system runs. A power outage is the same as your laptop being simply plugged out of an outlet.

The case might be different, if there was a power surge when the electricity comes back though, as it may lead to some data loss/corruption.

Hope this helps.

Comment: The transformer should handle voltage variations, it's unlikely the input voltage into the laptop will vary +/- 0.5v in normal operation, even if there's a power surge.

Comment: Thank You for the answer...